# What's the equivalent of Array.map for ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I can call `map()` on an array to iterate through it and return another array, like so:

```
[1,2,3].map( (value, index) => value * index )
```

What if I want to do the same over a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set(0, 1);
myMap.set(1, 2);
myMap.set(2, 3);
```

This isn't valid:

```
myMap.map( (value, index) => value * index )
```

There's a forEach but that's not the same.

Is there a quick shorthand way to generate an array from a `Map`, like `map()` does on an array?

– hopefully that sentence makes sense.

Comment: What do you expect it to return? You accept a key and an index, but return only a scalar value. Is it supposed to be an array as a result?

Comment: @zerkms same as the array example – iterates through each element of the map and returns an array of the computed values from the mapped function. resulting array should have the same number of elements as the original map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the result must be an array then you can use the [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Map.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries):

```
Array.from(myMap.entries()).map(([key, value]) => key * value)
```

alternatively you could [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the iterator:

```
[...myMap.entries()].map(...)
```

Comment: Both seem to work well. The second option is pretty shorthand too :)

Comment: Map.map should totally be in the specs

Comment: @Ben it's not obvious what type should be returned then - another map or an array.

Comment: Good point. Could either return an array with implicit index or a map with the original keys..

Comment: They could also add `mapValues`, that keep the same key but map the values.

Comment: @skylve unless it requires lodash.